# XML as an value of html input attribute using XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I have an XML like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE myxml SYSTEM  "xyz.dtd">
<myxml payloadID="__PAYLOADID__" timestamp="__TIMESTAMP__" xml:lang="en-US">
   <Header>
      <From>
      <Credential domain="test">
        <Identity>blahblah&amp;test</Identity>
      </Credential>
      </From>
   </Header>
  <Extrinsic name="GroupLineID"/>
</myxml>
```

I am trying to create HTML page where above XML need to be placed as value of attribute of html Input tag. I am using Java with Saxon to run XSLT. My XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">

<xsl:output name="test" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<html >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<xsl:element name="INPUT">
<xsl:attribute name="NAME">xml</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="TYPE">HIDDEN</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="VALUE"><xsl:copy-of select="saxon:serialize(myxml,'test')"></xsl:copy-of></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element> 
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Output of this XSLT is

```
<html xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<INPUT NAME="xml" TYPE="HIDDEN" VALUE="<myxml payloadID=&#34;__PAYLOADID__&#34; timestamp=&#34;__TIMESTAMP__&#34; xml:lang=&#34;en-US&#34;&gt;&#xA;   <Header&gt;&#xA;      <From&gt;&#xA;        <Credential domain=&#34;test&#34;&gt;&#xA;          <Identity&gt;blahblah&amp;amp;test</Identity&gt;&#xA;        </Credential&gt;&#xA;      </From&gt;&#xA;   </Header&gt;&#xA;   <Extrinsic name=&#34;GroupLineID&#34;/&gt;&#xA;</myxml&gt;">
</html>
```

But i would need to have xml and doctype declaraction also in output like below

```
 <html xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<INPUT NAME="xml" TYPE="HIDDEN" VALUE="<?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?><!DOCTYPE myxml SYSTEM &quot;xyz.dtd&quote;><myxml payloadID=&#34;__PAYLOADID__&#34; timestamp=&#34;__TIMESTAMP__&#34; xml:lang=&#34;en-US&#34;&gt;&#xA;   <Header&gt;&#xA;      <From&gt;&#xA;        <Credential domain=&#34;test&#34;&gt;&#xA;          <Identity&gt;blahblah&amp;amp;test</Identity&gt;&#xA;        </Credential&gt;&#xA;      </From&gt;&#xA;   </Header&gt;&#xA;   <Extrinsic name=&#34;GroupLineID&#34;/&gt;&#xA;</myxml&gt;">
</html>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Neither the XML declaration nor the DOCTYPE declaration are part of the XSLT data model so the XSLT processor does not have access to those parts of an XML input document. Using http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ you might be able to get the DOCTYPE however.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the XML declaration included, why have you said `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` in the `xsl:output` declaration?

Similarly, you can get a DOCTYPE declaration in the output of saxon:serialize if you use the `doctype-system` and `doctype-public` attributes of `xsl:output`.